# Setting Bootstrap 3 MVC 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I develop ASP.NET MVC 4 application using Visual Studio 2012 then I installed package html5shiv and Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC version 2.0.0 that using Twitter.Bootstrap 3.0.0 on its package.

After doing some setup and run the project, I've got the display problem. Maybe this picture can explain what are the problems:
[image]

From the picture there are 3 problems:

1. `<div class="container body-content">` is on top of `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse narvar-fixed-top">`
2. I think `<div class="container body-content">` should be `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse narvar-fixed-top">` so that the About text is displayed
3. I create Administration Dropdown Navigation Menu but it doesn't display the sub menus. This problem only occurs in IE 9, if I deploy to Firefox 28 the sub menus are displayed.

How to solve these?

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/base")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap/theme")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Html.Partial("_html5shiv")
    </head>
    <body>
        @Html.Partial("_NavBar")

        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)

        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <div class="footer">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

_NavBar.cshtml

```
@helper ActiveItem(string actionName, string controllerName, string areaName)
{
    if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == actionName &&
        ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == controllerName &&
        (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] == null || ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString() == areaName))
    {
        @:active
    }
}

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="@ActiveItem("Index", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li class="@ActiveItem("About", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li class="@ActiveItem("Contact", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li class="@ActiveItem("Index", "Client", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Client", "Index", "Client")</li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subsidiary Client</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Status</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Invoice Status</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Time Keeper Status</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Site.css

```
body {
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #b94a48;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #b94a48;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #b94a48;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Since it only happens in IE 9, first make sure the site is not running in compatibility mode or is not on the Compatibility list in IE settings.  Click the little 'broken page' icon in your address bar.

Comment: @L_7337 Compability mode is off, if it is on, then all menu in navigation bar will disappear

Comment: The only other thing I can think would be to check if there are any "z-index" set on the page or in the layout/css. And try getting rid of your bootstrap theme.  Just remove the extras and see if it works.